# hold key down until event C++

Tags: c++, interface, keyboard, simulate

So I am making a program in C++ that is supposed to hold down the C key whenever the W key is not being pressed AND release the C key whenever W is being pressed.
The simple specs I was given are: do not use the SendInput function, and do not allow the program to spam input the button it's supposed to be holding down. 
The algorithm I have implemented so far works to all ends of the specs, however, the function I was told would would hold down the key until told otherwise, is only tapping the c key once for a fraction of a second. 
The function I use to press is: 
`keybd_event('C', 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);`
The full implementation I have made is as follows:

```
        if (!GetAsyncKeyState('W'))
            pressed = true;
        else
            pressed = false;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)) {
            keybd_event('C', 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
            cout << "c released\n";
            cout << "\n\ninput password\n\n";
            getPass();
            cout << "\n\npassowrd accepted\n\n";
        }

        if (inner != pressed) {
            if (pressed) {
                keybd_event('C', 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0, 0);
                cout << "c pressed\n";
                inner = pressed;
            }else {
                keybd_event('C', 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
                cout << "c released\n";
                inner = pressed;
            }
        }
```

In conclusion, does anyone know how to get the keybd_event function to hold down the key until it is told to release it as demonstrated? Or does anyone know of a non-SendInput function that can do this? For this program I also used windows.h for those who may not recognize the functions present. Thank you for your time. :-)

Comment: Your use of `GetAsyncKeyState()` return values is wrong. And whoever wrote the spec telling you to not use `SendInput()` doesn't know what they are talking about.

Comment: actually, the GetAsyncKeyState() part is working perfectly, the print messages print exactly when they're supposed to so no issue there.
also the SendInput() part is to avoid interference with another program that's trying to detect it.

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState()` returns < 0 if the requested key is currently held down. So in `if (!GetAsyncKeyState('W')) pressed = true; else pressed = false;` you are setting `pressed` to `true` if the key is NOT held down, which seems backwards to me. As for `SendInput()`, `keybd_event()` is a legacy API that was replaced by `SendInput()`, and it just calls `SendInput()` internally on modern systems. `SendInput()` is the correct API to simulate input events. Avoiding `SendInput()` just so another program won't detect you is wrong, such a program would just equally detect `keydb_event()` events.

Comment: so yea the logic seems confusing there, but "pressed" is actually referring to whether or not C should be pressed not whether or not W is being pressed. Also I didn't know that about sendinput, in that case, what would be the sendinput command for holding down a key?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput)

Comment: I have read the documentation and the supplementary, I still cannot find an argument or function that explicitly holds down a key.

Comment: Holding down a key is no more than just simulating a down event without an up event, just like you do with `keybd_event()`. What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: exactly like before, it only presses the c key once and does not hold it down at all, even with the keyup event completely removed from the code.